# How to extract an Excel Graph VBA code?

Tags: vba, graph

How can I see, extract, or convert a Graph that is formatted to my liking into VBA code? When I right click on the excel tab and click on View Code all I see is the properties of the graph, but I want to see the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the macro recorder, then create a chart using the settings you like, then stop the recorder and you will have some code to look at. Excel doesn't create VBA code when you create a chart normally, only if you switch on the recorder.

Comment: How to turn on macro recorder would be a helpful part of this answer